# EditText focus dont work(android)

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, scrollview

Sorry for my English. I have 3 EditText and and they are in ScrollView. when you click on one of the EditText, ScrollView descends down and It focuses on EditText we chose. But if i click any EditText of three it scroll down and focus only EditText `city` no matter what I chose EditText. I do not know why, I ask your help

This **xml** i have 3 editText `city`, `adress` and `zip`

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="#26ffffff"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/adress"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@null"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:ems="15"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:hint="Adress"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textColor="#c9c9c9"
                                android:textColorHint="#c9c9c9"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                                android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
                                android:background="#26ffffff"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                >

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/zip"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:background="@null"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:ems="15"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:hint="ZIP"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:textColor="#c9c9c9"
                                    android:textColorHint="#c9c9c9"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                                android:background="#26ffffff"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                >

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/city"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:background="@null"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:ems="15"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:hint="City"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:textColor="#c9c9c9"
                                    android:textColorHint="#c9c9c9"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>
```

My code

```
 //adress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adress);
//        zip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zip);
//        city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);

    adress.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    isKeyboardShown(adress.getRootView(), adress);
                    zip.clearFocus();
                    city.clearFocus();
                }});

            zip.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    isKeyboardShown(zip.getRootView(), zip);
                    adress.clearFocus();
                    city.clearFocus();
                }});

            city.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    isKeyboardShown(city.getRootView(), city);
                    zip.clearFocus();
                    adress.clearFocus();
                }});

//method, if keyboard show -> scroll down
 private boolean isKeyboardShown(View rootView, TextView text) {
        /* 128dp = 32dp * 4, minimum button height 32dp and generic 4 rows soft keyboard */
        final int SOFT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_DP_THRESHOLD = 128;

        Rect r = new Rect();
        rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        DisplayMetrics dm = rootView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        /* heightDiff = rootView height - status bar height (r.top) - visible frame height (r.bottom - r.top) */
        int heightDiff = rootView.getBottom() - r.bottom;
        /* Threshold size: dp to pixels, multiply with display density */
        boolean isKeyboardShown = heightDiff > SOFT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_DP_THRESHOLD * dm.density;

        Log.e( "isKeyboardShown ? " + isKeyboardShown + ", heightDiff:" + heightDiff + ", density:" + dm.density
                + "root view height:" + rootView.getHeight() + ", rect:" + r, "sd");
        //check keyboard show or not
        if(isKeyboardShown) {
            scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            text.requestFocus();
        } else {


        }

        return isKeyboardShown;
    }
```

**UDP**

Now code is

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

adress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adress);
        zip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zip);
        city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);

scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView3);

 //down scroll view
        downScroll();

        //focuses edit text
        focusEditText();

}

//its method i create
public void focusEditText() {
        adress.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("click", "onMtouch");
                adress.setFocusable(true);
                adress.requestFocus();
                zip.clearFocus();
                city.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });


        zip.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("click", "onMtouch");
                zip.setFocusable(true);
                zip.requestFocus();
                adress.clearFocus();
                city.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });

        city.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("click", "onMtouch");
                city.setFocusable(true);
                city.requestFocus();
                zip.clearFocus();
                adress.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

//scroll down 
 public void downScroll() {
        adress.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                isKeyboardShown(adress.getRootView(), adress);
            }});

        zip.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                isKeyboardShown(zip.getRootView(), zip);
            }});

        city.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                isKeyboardShown(city.getRootView(), city);
            }});
    }


//method scroll down
private boolean isKeyboardShown(View rootView, EditText text) {
        /* 128dp = 32dp * 4, minimum button height 32dp and generic 4 rows soft keyboard */
        final int SOFT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_DP_THRESHOLD = 128;

        Rect r = new Rect();
        rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        DisplayMetrics dm = rootView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        /* heightDiff = rootView height - status bar height (r.top) - visible frame height (r.bottom - r.top) */
        int heightDiff = rootView.getBottom() - r.bottom;
        /* Threshold size: dp to pixels, multiply with display density */
        boolean isKeyboardShown = heightDiff > SOFT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_DP_THRESHOLD * dm.density;

        Log.e( "isKeyboardShown ? " + isKeyboardShown + ", heightDiff:" + heightDiff + ", density:" + dm.density
                + "root view height:" + rootView.getHeight() + ", rect:" + r, "sd");

        if(isKeyboardShown) {
            scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        } else {
            if (!adressText.equals("") && !cityText.equals("") && isOnline()) {
                new GeocoderTask().execute(new String[]{cityText + "," + adressText});
            }
        }

        return isKeyboardShown;
    }
```

Comment: In your isKeyboardShown method parameters isn't TextView text should be EditText text , because you want to focus EditText right

Comment: @L-X thanks for answer. Strange, but after the change it still only focused in `city`

Comment: Try this ,inside your adress.getViewTree Observer instead of clearing other two edit text focus ,add adress.requestFocus() here and same for other too with their respective names

Comment: @L-X, no its not work, still only focused in `city`

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure it out , now I am assuming you just want the editext whichever is clicked to be in focus , then just simply use address.onTouchEvent() function and inside it requestFocus() can be called ,

Comment: @L-X yes, i whant click editText->focus it. i update my question, its not work. Now it focused only `adress`

Comment: Call onDownScroll inside onTouchListener function also in your onDownScroll function send a parameter for example 1 for address and 2 for city and 3 for zip and inside onDownScroll function setup a switch function which calls only one edittext.getViewTreeObserver()

Comment: did it really work , because I am going to be honest with you i really don't know about getViewTreeObserver function do I am still new to android